# Why is my string being converted to a tuple when I append it to my list?

Tags: python, string, csv, class, parsing

I am reading lines from a csv file and using that to initiate instances of a VM class, which is then appended to a list, called vm_list. I have two different ips being appended, "ip_address" and "ilo_ip, which are row[1] and row[2] respectively. What I noticed is that ilo_ip is being appended as a tuple, but if I check the type before it is appended, it is a string. I even tried typecasting it to a string in my append statement to make sure it goes through as a string, but it doesn't. Any idea why that could be?

```
Im using
Python 3.9.6
```

linux_inventory.csv:

```
testname 10.10.10.10 11.11.11.11 fake_location fake_classification fake_server_type fake_end_of_life fake_os_version fake_domain fake_serial_number fake_function
```

reader.py

```
import csv

#virtual_machine

class vm:
  def __init__(self, name, ip_address, ilo_ip, location, classification, server_type, end_of_life, os_version, domain, serial_number, function):
    self.name = name
    self.ip_address = ip_address
    self.ilo_ip = ilo_ip, 
    self.location = location,
    self.classification = classification, 
    self.server_type = server_type,
    self.end_of_life = end_of_life
    self.os_version = os_version
    self.domain = domain
    self.serial_number = serial_number
    self.function = function

    
vm_list = []
with open('linux_inventory.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
       
        vm_list.append(vm(row[0],row[1],str(row[2]),row[3],row[4],row[5],row[6],row[7],row[8],row[9],row[10]))
        print(row) # output: ['testname', '10.10.10.10', '11.11.11.11', 'fake_location', 'fake_classification', 'fake_server_type', 'fake_end_of_life', 'fake_os_version', 'fake_domain', 'fake_serial_number', 'fake_function']
        print(row[2]) #output 11.11.11.11
        print(type(row[2])) #output: <class 'str'>
        
        
for vm in vm_list:
    print(vm.ip_address) #output: 10.10.10.10
    print(type(vm.ip_address)) # output: <class 'str'>
    print(vm.ilo_ip) #output: 11.11.11.11
    print(type(vm.ilo_ip)) #output: <class 'tuple'>
```

Comment: Take the comma off all those lines like `self.ilo_ip = ilo_ip,`. The comma makes a tuple.

Comment: Also, there's no way `print(vm.ilo_ip)` printed what you say it did.

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue

```
    self.ilo_ip = ilo_ip, # this is equivalent to self.ilo_ip = (ilo_ip,)
    self.location = location,
    self.classification = classification, 
    self.server_type = server_type,
```

In python, tuples do not need to be defined with parentheses. A single comma is enough. Remove the commas at the end of each line and it should be fixed.

```
    self.ilo_ip = ilo_ip
    self.location = location
    self.classification = classification
    self.server_type = server_type
```